# How to validate received messages from Websocket Connection using robot framework

Tags: websocket, automation, integer, robotframework

The connection using websocket is successfully created. Then I would like to send a message to the echo mock server and validate the answer. I send "hello", but I get a numerical value back as if the message was converted to an integer. The answer should be also "hello", but the robot framework returns a numeric value.

```py
Echo
    ${my_websocket}=  WebSocketClient.Connect  wss://*************/websocket
    ${result}=  WebSocketClient.Recv  ${my_websocket}
    Should Be Equal  Connected!!!!!  ${result}

    ${result2}=  WebSocketClient.Send  ${my_websocket}  "Hello"
    Log    ${result2}
    Should Be Equal  Hello  ${result2}

    WebSocketClient.Close  ${my_websocket}
```

The ${result2} returns value "13" instead of "Hello".